# Embed.ly PHP: Undefined provider_url and provider_name

Tags: php, html, embed

I'm working with Embed.ly PHP, which you can find [here](https://github.com/embedly/embedly-php). I've been trying to test out embedding with a few other sites, like articles from MLB or ESPN.

Working from examples/oembed.php, I replaced the first few links in the `$urls` array with a couple different links to see how they would embed. The links I tried:

http://sports.espn.go.com/ncf/news/story?id=6688739

http://mlb.mlb.com/news/article.jsp?ymd=20110621&content_id=20815268&vkey=news_mlb&c_id=mlb

The errors I get in their place:

```
Notice: Undefined index: provider_url

Notice: Undefined index: provider_name
```

I'm fairly sure embed.ly supports embedding from these sites, but I can't figure out why I'm getting errors for these links.

**EDIT** Some additional info

When I use `echo '<p>' . $oembed['type'] . '</p>';` right before each embed, the two above result in "error" being printed... some of the other ones print "video" or "photo".

**EDIT2** My code: http://pastebin.com/Z1P0K31E

I changed a one thing besides what I already noted: `require_once` path was changed to correct path of `Embedly.php`. That file is left exactly as it was found on github.

Comment: $oembed['type'] on an empty variable will cause the error you're seeing. The variables are some how not properly being populated, is there an error stack you can print out for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue concerns arrays that have indices `provider_url` and `provider_name` that are empty.

So for example, there is `$some_array['provider_url']` and `$some_array['provider_name']` that have empty values. I would find out where these variables are, and then I would track backwards or if you have some access to an error stack / trace stack, that would also be helpful.

stdClass Object ( [error_code] => 401 [error_message] => This service requires an Embedly Pro account [type] => error )`You'll need a pro account whatever that is. That's the error message I got back from using their API. Case closed.`

Comment: @FinalForm Have you looked at the source code I provided? They are only used in one spot. It seems that it cannot retrieve the provider_url and name and because it is not retrieving these it does not embed the articles.

Comment: @FinalForm Posted. I would highly encourage you to look at the github link I posted.

Comment: @FinalForm Okay, let me know what you did to fix this.